# Is there a way to invalidate a Pose in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, marker, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I often publish a Pose message to quickly and easily view things in rviz.  And I would like a way to programatically (through a message) tell rviz to delete the pose from view.

The scenario is that I have a robot which grabs objects on a table.  And I want to display the pose of the object in rviz.  I do several runs with different objects and positions.  So between runs I would like to clear the previous runs from view.  This is easy to do with rviz markers, but not with regular Pose messages.

I have tried publishing with a 0 time stamp and empty frame_id with no luck in deleting the frame.  I have observed tf frames becoming gray and disappearing, how is that done?

Can a new marker type be added to display axes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9646/is-there-a-way-to-invalidate-a-pose-in-rviz?/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could publish an [arrow marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Arrow_.28ARROW.3D0.29), instead.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-06**:
Or a triplet of arrows as your axis.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested by the other answers, there is no way to do it exactly as you requested.

However, if you simply re-publish the pose with giant values, like xyz = 99999,99999,99999, it will effectively become invisible.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1